Plotting 2 histogram on top and bottom part of a single plot
I want to draw two histogram on same plot window but placed vertically. One such example can be found at https://blogs.sas.com/content/graphicallyspeaking/files/2013/11/MirrorHistogramVert.png
Below is my code
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
dat = rbind(data.frame('val' = rnorm(100), 'met' = 'Metric1'), data.frame('val' = rt(100, 2), 'met' = 'Metric12'))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = val, y = met, color = met)) + geom_histogram()

However I am getting below error
Error in `geom_histogram()`:
! Problem while computing stat.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `setup_params()`:
! `stat_bin()` must only have an x or y aesthetic.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I also want to add probability curve for Normal distribution for both histogram.
Any suggestion what could be the right approach will be very helpful

@stefan Thanks for this. I have corrected my original post

You could do two separate layers for the two groups, using y = -after_stat(count) in the second layer (the default for geom_histogram is y = after_stat(count).
Ensure the breaks for both layers are the same so that the bins line up.
ggplot(dat, aes(x = val, fill = met)) + 
  geom_histogram(data    = dat[dat$met == 'Metric1',], 
                 breaks  = seq(-40, 10, 0.5),
                 colour  = "black",
                 alpha   = 0.3) +
  geom_histogram(data    = dat[dat$met == 'Metric12', ],
                 breaks  = seq(-40, 10, 0.5),
                 mapping = aes(y = -after_stat(count)),
                 colour  = "black",
                 alpha   = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('blue3', 'red3')) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-10, 10)) +
  labs(y = 'count') +
  theme_bw(20) +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank())



This is very good. I also wanted to add normal density plots for both histograms. How can I do this?

@Bogaso if you mean density kernel estimates, that's essentially the same, using geom_density instead of geom_histogram. You also need to specify the positive after_stat(count) for the aesthetics of the positive variable. If you mean you want an appropriately scaled normal distribution with its mean and standard deviation dictated by the data, this is possible but quite involved and is essentially a completely new question.

@Bogaso, you could simply pre-calculate the density plot via density() and then also just multiply one of the metrics with -1.
